# How can I convert X11 keysym to the string that will be typed?

Tags: x11, xorg

I have a keysym number (for example 0x1a2, which is `XK_breve` in `keysymdef.h`, in latin2 charset). Is there a way get a string that will be typed when key emitting that keysym will be pressed?

I tried using `XKeysymToString`, but that gives me the full name of the symbol (`breve`) instead of the character that will be typed (`˘`).

There's `XLookupString` that does something similar, but it requires XKeyEvent which I don't have (I only have a keysym number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Xutf8LookupString(3) which will also take into account the input method and xkb rules in effect.

Not all keypresses directly generate a string.

Example:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  KeySym keysym = 0x1a2;

  Display* display = XOpenDisplay(":0");

  XIM xim = XOpenIM(display, 0, 0, 0);
  XIC xic = XCreateIC(xim, XNInputStyle, XIMPreeditNothing | XIMStatusNothing, NULL);

  XKeyPressedEvent event;
  event.type = KeyPress;
  event.display = display;
  event.state = 0;
  event.keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, keysym);

  char buffer[32];
  KeySym ignore;
  Status return_status;
  Xutf8LookupString(xic, &event, buffer, 32, &ignore, &return_status);
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Xutf8LookupString` also requires XKeyPressedEvent, which I don't have. I know that not all keypresses generate a string (e.g. Ctrl won't), but I assumed that all valid keysyms should uniquely represent a string?

Comment: No, not all valid keysyms represent a string in the way you suggest it (breve -> ˘). You can easily make up an XKeyEvent: it's just a C struct. Your suggested XLookupString is a deprecated / compat function.

Comment: I was unaware of that, thanks. XKeyEvent contains lots of Window pointers - is it acceptable to set them all to NULL?

Comment: The Window aren't pointers, but XIDs (integer ids like pids). X*LookupString don't care about the value of ev.window, etc: only ev.display, ev.type, ev.keycode and ev.state matter.

Comment: I tried callsing Xutf8LookupString with hand-crafted XKeyReleasedEvent, but for now it returns XLookupNone for all possible keycodes. Also, it does not accept KeySyms, it requires keycodes.

Comment: 1. Xutf8LookupString expects a KeyPress event 2. You can convert a keysym to a keycode with XKesymToKeycode() (notice that this will not use any modifiers: it will return the same keycode for asciitilde and grave on a US keyboard) 3. You should also create a simple input context with XCreateIC(preedit_nothing|status_nothing) if you're using Xutf8LS or XmbLS. I'll add an example when I get time.

Comment: 1. Yes, that was my error. 2. I somehow managed to miss that function when searching, thanks. 3. Yes, did that already (without it I got segfaults).
I'll add my code as an example to your answer, feel free to edit to your liking.